# How can i get the requested url in a webservice using asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am writing a WebService and wants to find out the URL the client used to call my WebMethod.

**Ok..i will explain it in detail..**

Suppose i have a webservice (http://myWebservice/HashGenerator/HashValidator.asmx)
as follows

```
[WebMethod]
public string ValidateCode(string sCode)
{
  //need to check requested url here.The call will be coming from different sites
  //For example www.abc.com/accesscode.aspx
}
```

please send me a solution for this.

Comment: Please give more detail. What do you mean by "get the requested url"? Are you just trying to download the contents?

Comment: I think he is writing a WebService and wants to find out the URL the client used to call his WebMethod.

Comment: Ok, then Darin is right: you can't do this unless you pass it as argument to your web method or some custom HTTP header.

Answer (score 18):

If you are in .asmx webservice and needs to get the current url, you can try the below.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Url
```

Comment: Why would he want to get the current URL? He already knows it.

Comment: this will get the current webservice url..i want the URL the client used to call my WebMethod.

Comment: @user give an example? are you trying to find the host name in which your webservice is located?

Answer (score 5):

Your question is not very clear. If you are trying to get the URL of the ASPX page calling the web service then you can't do this unless you pass it as argument to your web method or some custom HTTP header. Here's an example of a call:

```
var proxy = new YourWebServiceProxy();
string currentUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString();
proxy.ValidateCode("some code", currentUrl);
```

and your web service method now looks like this:

```
[WebMethod]
public string ValidateCode(string sCode, string callerUrl)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I am writing a WebService and wants to find out the URL the client used to call my WebMethod.

Comment: As I said, if the client doesn't pass this information as an argument to your web service you will never be able to get it. Imagine a console application client consuming your web service: there's no even a notion of URL there.

Comment: Then Ramesh or my answer should help you.

Comment: @Darin read his comment again, he wants the Context.Request.Url

Comment: @Turrau, yeah maybe you are right, now that I read his comment more carefully, but this makes no sense as you already know this information inside the web method.

Comment: @Turrau, example of what? Now that it is clear what he is trying to do, the only way to achieve it is to pass this URL as argument of the web method. I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: Is it clear to you? He keeps repeating he wants "the URL the client USED TO CALL my WebMethod" (emphasis by me) ...

Comment: @Turrau, so then when you suggested using `this.Context.Request.Url` he explicitly commented on your answer that that's not the URL he wants.

Comment: thats why I asked for an example of what he really wants ... but whatever, as long as he doesn't explains what he wants, why should we argue ...

Comment: @Turrau, totally agree with you.

Answer (score 5):

To get information of the client's previews request to current website you can use the `UrlReferrer` as follow:

```
//To get the Absolute path of the URI use this
string myPreviousAbsolutePath = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.AbsolutePath;

//To get the Path and Query of the URI use this
string myPreviousPathAndQuery = Page.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I just realized what I'm doing is actually redundant as the ajax request already includes a header called Referer. I'm leaving the code below as it is still valid if you want to pass a custom header and then access it on the server.

```
HttpContext.Current.Handler //This is null when using a web service
```

My work around is to add a custom header to all web service calls (using Jquery .ajax). The header contains the URL of the calling page:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: { 'CurrentUrl': '' + document.URL + '' }
});
```

Then on the server get the custom header inside of your web method:

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CurrentUrl"]
```

The main reason I want the URL of the caller page is I use querystring parameters for debugging. 
The line below will give you all query string parameters from the page that called the web service.

```
HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["CurrentUrl"]).Query)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need this:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string mywebmethod()
{
string parameters =  HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery.ToString();
return parameters
}
```